# shell script behaves differently from Automator

Tags: shell, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, automator

I have a couple scripts to clean up some generated HTML; a python script using BeautifulSoup, and a Ruby script.  These remove unneeded tags and attributes, transform symbols to html encodings, get rid of excessive newline characters, and make sure the files are encoded in valid UTF-8.

I can run these two scripts from the command line and they work as expected; and I can run them in this shell script from the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
HTMLPath=$1

echo $HTMLPath 2>&1 >> /Users/me/Desktop/log.txt
/usr/bin/python /Users/me/DevProj/script/cleanHTML.py "$HTMLPath" 2>&1 >> /Users/me/DevProj/logs/log.txt
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby /Users/me/DevProj/script/cleanupHtml.rb "$HTMLPath" 2>&1 >> /Users/me/DevProj/logs/log.txt
```

and this also gives the expected result.

However when I run them from Automator, which feeds them a list of html files to process, the python script removes the html encoding `&#x2212;` from the file (HTML encoding for minus symbol `-`) and I end up with white space instead.  The problem is, I need those minus signs to remain, preferably as `&minus;` and I need it to be run from Automator.

I thought it might have something to do with the version of python that the Automator shell was using, so I created the shell script to ensure it would use same bash shell I use on the command line, /bin/bash.

Has anyone else out there run into this issue?  Am I doing something wrong from Automator?

In the script I have added `python --version >> log.txt` but it won't output the python version to the log... I have a sneaking suspicion that Automator is using its own older python library.

**Note:** I have only encountered this problem when there are `&#x2212;` strings in the input file.  It otherwise runs fine from Automator.  Automator is causing the problem.

Comment: On the side, is there a reason why these two scripts can't be combined into one?

Comment: Not really, just that I wrote one in ruby first because I was familiar with the ruby regular expression; then a friend told me about BeautifulSoup and sent me a script. I could put the regular expressions into the python script-- just haven't written python regular expressions yet.

Comment: What if you were to try putting everything in the Ruby script and using something like [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) instead of Beautiful Soup (in this case)?

Comment: The only problem so far is the '&#x2212;' character so I suppose I could just substitute it before running the beautifulsoup line.

Comment: So that character is being taken out by both the Ruby and Python scripts?

Comment: No, as far as I know, just the Python script is doing it.  But, frequently there are invalid utf-8 characters in the script so I need to run the python script before I can run the ruby script; otherwise ruby will complain.

Comment: There should be a way to do the same thing in Ruby for that UTF-8 character fixing issue, as well... might want to keep searching? Anyway, I would still suggest trying to fit it all into your Ruby script in this case... that way it's all in one place (for the most part) and you won't get be getting the weird substitution at the end.  Not saying Ruby is better than Python (I actually use Python more often, myself) but sometimes it's not a bad idea to consolidate your scripts when possible.

Comment: I still want to know why Automator shell script (same for from applescript) is running the python script differently than when I run the script from the shell.  I could rewrite the functionality of the python beautifulsoup code into my ruby script using nokogiri; or I could just run the scripts from the shell instead of Automator.  But I still want to know why why why (head banging on desk sound)

Comment: but thanks for your suggestions!  I turned to Python & beautiful soup when Ruby couldn't seem to handle the invalid utf-8 chars; if nokogiri is well documented I may turn to that to try to handle the invalid chars.